# Store JSON retrieved via AJAX in a cookie

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I want to save some json data in a cookie and retrieve it in a different page with jquery cookie
Here is how i get the data and store it.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "V2_Loader.aspx/GetMenuData",
            data: "{id:" + id + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
            menus = response.d;
            $.cookie('menu-data', menus);
          }
     }
```

In a different page I try to retrieve it  like this.

```
 menus = JSON.parse($.cookie("menu-data"));
```

but I get "JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character"
I've tried turning on the json flag
$.cookie.json = true;
before storing it and when i try to print it out.
like this

```
        var result;
            for (var i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
                result += menus[i].menuText + ', ';
            }
            alert(result);
```

I get this an array of undefined printed like here [printed array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46QiM.png)

this is how my response looks like [response](http://pastebin.com/h1M1zBU3)

Any suggestions as to how i should be storing this and retrieving it?

Comment: I've removed ASP.NET references in your tags and title, as your problem is client side and the server side technology providing the data does not matter.

Comment: `data: "{id:" + id + "}"` should just be: `data: {id: id }`

Comment: id is a variable passed to the function that retrieves the data, thats why im concatenating it to the data string and it seems like it works no problem

Comment: @hjpotter92 that is incorrect. He is specifically posting JSON to the server, hence the json contentType.

Comment: Why are you using `async: false`?

Comment: @irco As a rule of thumb, never build json strings via string concatenation. Create a javascript object and pass it to `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: I wrote a cookies library for a JS which lets you write native JS data to cookies. It handles the serialization and encoding for you. It's linked in my profile. One thing to note, though, is that you may be running into issue with max cookie size causing your data to be truncated and un-parseable.

Comment: @Keving B The async:false is gone it was somebody else's old code, I Got rid of it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternate solution to using a cookie, you could instead use `sessionStorage` in the browser.

```
$ajax({
  ...,
  success: function (response) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('menu-data', JSON.stringify(response.d));
  }
});

var menus = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('menu-data'));
```

Comment: oh that'd be awesome I had no idea i could do that, but when I do JSON.parse I get 'Invalid character' My response looks like valid json though

Comment: Hmm, after some playing around in Chrome's console, it seems that the default way `sessionStorage` stringifies the data has a bug when being parsed back out as an object using `JSON.parse()`. I've edited my response with what should work now.

Comment: ah that worked, awesome I didn't even know sessionStorage existed thanks for the suggestion, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in `$.cookie('menu-data', menus);`, `menus` isn't json. You need to turn it into json.

```
$.cookie('menu-data', JSON.stringify(menus));
```

Due to the size of your json, you may be hitting a cookie length limitation.

Comment: I thought by requesting JSON the response would be json, I've switched the line, but I can't seem to be able to turn it back into a json collection.
should this work:  var tst = jQuery.parseJSON($.cookie("menu-data")); ?

Comment: Yes, that should work, however *"Due to the size of your json, you may be hitting a cookie length limitation."*

Comment: Since you set `dataType: "json",`, jquery automatically converts the json to a object. that's why you're able to do `menus = response.d;`. Otherwise, `response.d` would be `undefined`.

Comment: ah I got you, I've reworked the json to be reduced to this
http://pastebin.com/f0gDQTRA  which is much smaller and whenever i try to convert it back I keep getting undefined, any ideas?